# Is it possible to run XCode Autolayout's constraint solver on command line?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

When I'm using Autolayout on Interface Builder, I can use **Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> All Frames - Update Frames** to generate a new XIB with the new frames that satisfy the actual constraints of the file.

Is it possible to run this command using the command line? I could almost answer this question with a big **NO**, but I want to be sure, because I'm about to work hard on Automator to get some specific tasks done and it would be much easier to run a normal script to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `ibtool` command:

```
ibtool /path/to/your.xib --write /path/to/new.xib --update-frames
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Do you know if there is a way to know all the tools included in the Command Line Tools package? I didn't know ibtool, and maybe there are other useful tools I don't know about (and I can't find the right words to get to useful results). Another little doubt: do you know if there's any command to apply a given size class to a XIB file? I don't think so, as this seems to be calculated on runtime in xcode when I select the desired class size, but maybe I'll have another surprise. Thanks, your answer will save me a lot of time!

Comment: You're welcome. `ibtool` is not actually part of the Command Line Tools (CLT) package. `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/ibtool` shows that it's part of the Essentials package which is part of the core OS install. That said, I don't know if it's just the stub until Xcode or CLT are installed. You can see what's in the CLT package using `pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables`. You can also look inside the Xcode.app bundle to see what it comes with, in particular look in Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin. You can use `man` to learn more about any commands of interest.